# How to group_by only if the group contains a certain value in a specific column

Tags: r

I have a dataset as follows

```
Pt    EVENT
123    GGG
123    Nor
123    tre
144    GGG
1667   tre
1667   Nor
1667   tre
```

I want to group_by and then the data as per my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295137/how-to-transpose-column-and-group-at-the-same-time/38295203#38295203) according to Pt but I am only interested in creating groups which contain Nor so the final dataset should be

```
Pt    
123   GGG      Nor   tre
1667  tre      Nor   tre
```

I have the answer from the previous question but I can't seem to only select specific *groups*. This is what I have tried but it gives me

```
Sankey<-EndoSubset %>%
  group_by(Pt) %>% 
  filter(EVENT == "Nor")
```

but obviously this just gives me rows containing Nor whereas I want all the rows for `Pt` that contains `Nor`

Comment: Isn't this the same as previous output.  I am not finding any difference in the expected output

Comment: Apologies @akrun. I have corrected the expected output

Comment: I posted a solution below

Answer (score 4):

We can try with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`, reshape from 'long' to 'wide' with `dcast`, then we check for columns 2:4 for "Nor" value, compare elementwise with `Reduce` and use the logical vector to subset the rows.

```
library(data.table)
res <- dcast(setDT(df1), Pt~rowid(Pt), value.var="EVENT", fill="")
res[res[, Reduce(`|`, lapply(.SD,`==`, "Nor" )) , .SDcols = 2:4]]
#     Pt   1   2   3
#1:  123 GGG Nor tre
#2: 1667 tre Nor tre
```

---

A compact option would be to `subset` the "Nor" rows before the `dcast` step

```
dcast(setDT(df1)[, if(any(EVENT=="Nor")) .SD, Pt], Pt~rowid(Pt), value.var ="EVENT")
#    Pt   1   2   3
#1:  123 GGG Nor tre
#2: 1667 tre Nor tre
```

---

If we are using `dplyr`, similar method as showed in the second option in `data.table` would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(Pt) %>%
   filter(any(EVENT=="Nor")) %>% 
   mutate(n = row_number())  %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   spread(n, EVENT)
#    Pt     1     2     3
#  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1   123   GGG   Nor   tre
#2  1667   tre   Nor   tre
```

---

Or using only `base R` methods

```
reshape(transform(df1[with(df1, ave(EVENT=="Nor", Pt, FUN=any)),],
   time = ave(seq_along(EVENT), Pt, FUN = seq_along)), direction="wide", idvar="Pt")
#    Pt EVENT.1 EVENT.2 EVENT.3
#1  123     GGG     Nor     tre
#5 1667     tre     Nor     tre
```

Comment: ...and if I want to check for Nor or GGG I use "Nor|GGG"  ?

Comment: @SebastianZeki  That should be the case with `grep`.  But, here I guess you can use `%in%` and `c("Nor", "GGG")`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your data looks, it might make sense to store the result as a list. Here is a base R a method to achieve that:

```
# split data by EVENT and check EVENT is in desired set 
# if yes, collect Pt into character vectors
myList <- lapply(split(df, df$Pt), function(i) {
                                  if("Nor" %in% as.character(i$EVENT)) {
                                    unlist(as.character(i$EVENT))}})
# drop list elements with length 0
myList <- myList[lengths(myList) > 0]
```

This returns a named list:

```
myList
$`123`
[1] "GGG" "Nor" "tre"

$`1667`
[1] "tre" "Nor" "tre"
```

If you want a data.frame and the lengths of the vectors are equal, as in the example, you could use `rbind` and `do.call`:

```
data.frame(do.call(rbind,temp))
      X1  X2  X3
123  GGG Nor tre
1667 tre Nor tre
```

Note that Pt is now contained in the rownames.

Thanks to @RichardScriven for reminding my about `lengths`.

Comment: `sapply(myList, length)` is the same as `lengths(myList)` in newer R versions, only slower.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `base R`

```
summary_df <- aggregate(data=df,EVENT~.,FUN = paste,collapse=",")
summary_df[grep("Nor",summary_df$EVENT),]
```